# Windows Installer not reconizing repair/upgrade; thinkis its a new install

Tags: windows, installer

Trying to update our companies software program to new version. Setup.exe installer is not detecting the original installation.  It is not giving us an option for "repair/upgrade", instead it proceeds as if it's a new installation. Could the windows installer be corrupt or a registry key be missing.

Windows 2008 R2

Comment: It could be that the version you are updating from is not upgradable to the version you are installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows installer is pretty much just a framework for multiple operations including file copying/running scripts and other activities needed to install software.

It knows what is installed through a combination of factors, most often simply a GUID string.

Most likely, the software you are trying to install is of sufficient different version that it is not compatible for an upgrade, or, the makers simply messed up the installer/used a different identifier when building the installer.

In any case, I'm not clear if this is software your company made or software you use. If it is software you use - contact the manufacturer of it, and if it is in house, contact the dev team - they are in a much better position to help you than us (without knowing the software in question)